# Feature test on a console Secret question

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-artisan

I'm gonna write a test for my artisan console command that I've used `secret()` method.

this is my console code:

```
public function handle(): void
{
    // Login process
    do {

        $email = $this->ask('Email address');
        $password = $this->secret('Password');

        ...

    } while (!$login);

    
}
```

and I write this test:

```
public function test_login_user()
{

    $this->artisan('command:run')
        ->expectsQuestion('Email address', 'user@domain.com')
        ->expectsQuestion('Password', 'password')
        ->assertExitCode(0);

}
```

But I get this error while I run the test (`php artisan test`)

```
  Method Mockery_1_Illuminate_Console_OutputStyle::askQuestion(<Closure===true>)() called out of order: expected order 1, was 2
```

Does anybody know what my mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have the questions in a `do...while` loop. You're expecting the order of questions to be 1) Email address and 2) Password, but when you're then looping, you're adding two more questions but you're not adding the expectations for them.

```php
$login = false;

do {

    $email = $this->ask('Email address');
    $password = $this->secret('Password');

    if ($password === 'password') {
        $login = true;
    }

} while (!$login);
```

If I run this and don't answer `password` and do another round of questions, the test case fails with the same error you get. But if I factor that into my test and add the second round of questions.

```php
$this->artisan('command:run')
    ->expectsQuestion('Email address', 'email@example.com')
    ->expectsQuestion('Password', 'password2')
    ->expectsQuestion('Email address', 'email@example.com')
    ->expectsQuestion('Password', 'password')
    ->assertExitCode(0);
```

Now my test case passes because and I can continue asserting the correct exit code.

Instead of looping, I'd recommend returning a message saying the command failed and telling them to run it again. Or update your test suite to factor in the loop, testing one case of the loop working it as enough IMO.